# how to instanciate CognitoUser to get user attribute in android sdk

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Previously we could just do "identityManager.getUserName" to get a userName for an authenticated app user. But now this is not the case with the updated android sdk "mysampleapp".

I am trying to retrieve userName attribute with the following code I found in the aws tutorials but I am getting error:

```
// Implement callback handler for getting details 
GetDetailsHandler getDetailsHandler = new GetDetailsHandler() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
    // The user detail are in cognitoUserDetails
     Map userAtts = new HashMap();
     userAtts = cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes();
     String userName = userAtts.get("given_name").toString();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Exception exception) { 
    // Getting the error here
}
};

// Fetch the user details 
cognitoUser.getDetailsInBackground(getDetailsHandler);
```

My question is how do I instanciate "cognitouser" variable in the above code?

I tried the following but it did not work. Gives me a "no identity error":

```
   CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this, userPool, keyID, 
   keySecrete);
   CognitoUser cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
```

I get the error:

```
onFailure==com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.exceptions.CognitoNotAuthorizedException:User-ID is null
```

The user is already logged in as authenticated user before I try to retrieve their userName.
Please help with any idea. I just need to instanciate "**cognitouser**" and get on with my work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a deprecated constructor of the CognitoUserPool class. This worked for me:

```
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this, awsConfiguration);
```